# Добрый день не приходят 2 вложения на почту,как исправить?

Tags: php

```
 $(".form-smeta").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST"
            , url: "smeta.php"
            , data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        return false;
    });  

<script>

 <?php 



    $from = "<ГенСтройФаворит>";

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$mailTo = $_POST['email'];} 
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}

    $file = "smeta.doc"; // файл
    $file2 = "smeta2.doc"; // файл
     // от кого
    $subject = "Пример нашего договора и сметы на ремонтно-строительные работы"; // тема письма
    $message = "Доброго дня, меня зовут . Я являюсь владельцем компании ГенСтройФаворит. 
    Ниже прикрепляю обещанный каталог и надеюсь, что Вы найдете для себя подходящий вариант.
    Вы можете в связаться со мной по любому из контактных телефонов:
    + - Велком 
    + - МТС"; // текст письма 

     $r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message,$file,$file2);
    function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file = false, $file2 = false){
        $separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
        // Заголовки для письма
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
        // если письмо с вложением
        if($file and $file2 ){
            $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
            $bodyMail .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"; // кодировка письма
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"; // задаем конвертацию письма
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
             $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
            $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
            $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";


            $fileRead = fopen($file, "r"); // открываем файл

            $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
            fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
            $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл

            $fileRead2 = fopen($file2, "r"); // открываем файл

            $contentFile2 = fread($fileRead2, filesize($file2)); // считываем его до конца
            fclose($fileRead2); // закрываем файл
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n"; 
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n\n";
            $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile2))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл


            $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
        // письмо без вложения
        }else{
            $bodyMail = $message;
        }
        $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers); // отправка письма
        return $result;
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Где вызов функции?

Comment: На ajax из js. $(".form-smeta").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST"
            , url: "smeta.php"
            , data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function () {
            $(".form-smeta")[0].reset();
            $("#message-send-ok").addClass("active");
        });
        return false;
    });

Comment: В представленном коде где вызов функции?

Comment: вот переписал проблема осталась

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87303/discussion-between---and-u-mulder).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$from = "<ГенСтройФаворит>";
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$mailTo = $_POST['email'];} 
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
$file = "smeta.doc"; // файл
$file2 = "smeta2.doc"; // файл
 // от кого
$subject = "Пример нашего договора и сметы на ремонтно-строительные работы"; // тема письма
$message = "Доброго дня, меня зовут . Я являюсь владельцем компании ГенСтройФаворит. 
Ниже прикрепляю обещанный каталог и надеюсь, что Вы найдете для себя подходящий вариант.
Вы можете в связаться со мной по любому из контактных телефонов:
+ - Велком 
+ - МТС"; // текст письма 

$r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file, $file2); // отправка письма c вложением
echo ($r)?'':'';
function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file = false, $file2 = false){
    $separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
    // Заголовки для письма
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
    // если письмо с вложением
    if($file){
        $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
        $bodyMail .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"; // кодировка письма
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable"; // задаем конвертацию письма
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название файла
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n\n"; // задаем название второго файла
        $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
        $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
        $fileRead = fopen($file, "r"); // открываем файл
        $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
        fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
        $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
        $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
        $fileRead = fopen($file2, "r"); // открываем файл
        $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file2)); // считываем его до конца
        fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n"; 
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file2))."?=\n\n";
        $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
        $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
    // письмо без вложения
    }else{
        $bodyMail = $message;
    }
    $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers); // отправка письма
    return $result;
}

?>
```